# Wrapping every component in shared-components with material-ui theme?

Tags: material-ui

I created a shared-components repository which is using material-ui theme to style each component. I import these components into my main repository which doesn't have material-ui installed.

I'm wondering if it's best practice to wrap every shared-component with my custom theme or if I should export the `<ThemeProvider>` and the main repository will wrap each shared-component it uses with the theme itself. The other option is to wrap the whole main repository's app with the theme provider but I'm not sure every page will be using material-ui.

Does anyone know what the best practice is in this case?